# What is the alternative in postgreSQL for MongoDB's findAndModify method?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, postgresql, database-migration

We are migrating the database of our Springboot application from MongoDB to TimescaleDB, which is an extension of PostgreSQL. The codebase uses MongoDB's findAndModify method in order to maintain the IDs of different tables. Whenever a new record is inserted, the counter for that particular table is incremented by 1. And the ID value present before last increment is used as the ID for the table's record.

PostgreSQL's upsert method seems similar to that of MongoDB's findAndModify method. Is there any other efficient way to handle this in PostgreSQL?

And what would be the alternative for MongoTemplate(which provides the support of findAndModify method) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If you just need a new value for inserting rows you can use `IDENTITY`, `SEQUENCE`, or even the old `SERIAL`. Now, do you need the value for anything else?

Comment: @TheImpaler As per existing design, we have one entity class but two different Mongo Collections use that same entity class . For example: Entity class will be Fuel Consumption. But, there will be two separate mongo collections - Car fuel Consumption and Bike Fuel Consumption. Both the collections will have same columns, but data will be different